# AngularJS - Um service não é "estático"?

Tags: angularjs

Partindo da ideia que os services são singletons ([All Services are singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)), se eu criar um service simples com variáveis "locais" e modifique essa em um controller, ao acessar esse valor em outro controller, ele deveria manter o valor, né?

Exemplo:

```js
angular.module("app", []);
angular.module("app").service("service", function() {
  
  var _count = 0;
  
  this.incrementCount = function() {
      _count ++;
      console.log(_count);
  };
  
});

angular.module("app").controller("ctrl1", function($scope, service) {
  $scope.increment = function() {
      service.incrementCount();
   }
});

angular.module("app").controller("ctrl2", function($scope, service) {
   $scope.increment = function() {
      service.incrementCount();
   }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
 <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
  
    <button ng-click="increment()" value="ctrl1" >Ctrl1 </button> 
    
  </div>

   <div ng-controller="ctrl2">
  
      <button ng-click="increment()" > Ctrl2 </button> 
     
  </div> 
  
</body>
</html>
```

Nesse exemplo, se analisar o console, ele incrementa o valor correto independente do controller que estiver, porém, no meu caso, acontece que eu só tenho um controller na pagina e quando vou para a próxima pagina (sem manter o template), esse valor reinicia em 0.

O modo em que faço pro sistema ir pra outra pagina é usando o objeto **window**: `window.location.href = "views/player.html"`

Faço desse modo porque minha aplicação roda em protocolo FILE e não consegui, pelo menos ainda, fazer de outro jeito, o que me impede de usar de templates (pelo menos não consegui usa-los).

Esse é mesmo o comportamento esperado?

Comment: Com ir para próxima página, sem manter o template, o que você quer dizer? É um redirecionamento pelo Angular utilizando $location?

Comment: Acabei de editar quando vi que faltou essa informação. É utilizando o objeto window. Por algum motivo, não consegui fazer ele ir pra outro página usando o $location em protocolo file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Eo acessar esse valor em outro controller, ele deveria manter o valor, né?

**Correto**, se este *service* consumido estiver sob o mesmo contexto. Se, por exemplo, você possuir a seguinte estrutura:

```
<div ng-app='app1'>
    <div ng-controller='ctrl1'>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-app='app2'>
    <div ng-controller='ctrl2'>
    </div>
</div>
```

E tanto `ctrl1` e `ctrl2` consumirem o mesmo serviço, seus valores irão divergir por estarem em duas aplicações diferentes; os *singletons* gerados para prover o serviço são distintos.

Quando você usa `window.location.href`, você está destruindo o contexto atual e criando um novo.

Uma possibilidade que talvez você queira explorar seria `ngInclude`, que permite a carga dinâmica de conteúdo parcial mantendo o escopo corrente. Assim:

```
<div ng-include="views/player.html">
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica! Vou dar uma pesquisada no ng-include e qualquer coisa dou um grito aqui

Comment: @PauloGustavo boa sorte!

Comment: Opa, desculpa a demora por um retorno. Por falta de tempo, acabei colocando no protocolo HTTP afins de fazer testes só. Agora que votei com esse problema, tentei fazer usando o ng-include, como sugeriu. Eu coloquei dentro do meu index, o código "div ng-include="views/progressBar">. porém, quando vou dar um inspect no html, ele aparece comentado http://puu.sh/lr5D8/60f2293955.png . Você sabe por que?

Comment: Ah, o problema é que faltava aspas simples. Mas de qualquer modo, parece que o navegador não permite isso, ele da o seguinte erro: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Desenvolvimento/workspace/BSSJs/views/progressBars.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: @PauloGustavo olá! Isto pode estar acontecendo porque você está executando seu projeto via um servidor web (IIS, Apache, etc.) via http ou https e tentando carregar o arquivo diretamente via protocolo `file:`, e isso viola o as regras do CORS. Tente utilizar uma URL relativa.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua atenção. Só dando um update nas informações, eu estou rodando no protocolo file, porém ainda sim não funciona. Os testes que fiz foi no chrome, e notei que outras pessoas tinham esse problema e no executor do navegador, eles passam uns parametros para desabilitar isso. No firefox funcionou perfeitamente e no qtwebkit também funcionou, já que lá podemos desabilitar depois de fazer o build. De qualquer forma, o ng-include funcionou. Muito obrigado por sua ajuda!! Abraços

Answer (score 3):

Ao efetuar uma troca utilizando `window.location`, o que acontece é uma troca de página pelo navegador, sendo assim, toda a aplicação angular é recarregada e os valores zerados. É como abrir tudo do zero.

Para manter o estado da aplicação, utilize o serviço de `$location` que o angular provê. Documentação aqui: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: Hmmmm, interessante. Usando o window.location, como você disse, faz ele recarregar tudo.. mas o que acontece com as coisas que estão na memoria ? O AngularjS tenta forçar o GC a limpar ? Algo assim?

E sobre o uso do $location, você sabe dizer se é possível utilizar ele normalmente no protocolo file?

Comment: O Angular não faz nada de gc, o navegador faz isso jogando tudo fora, sem nem questionar o angular e passando para a próxima página. O que seria o protocolo file?

Comment: Não sei definir ele muito bem, mas de ligeira, é abrir um arquivo html no teu computador pelo brower. É o file://